# Why didn't change url in browser field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I want to get in my browser url field like this:

```
/posts/title_post instead /posts/id
```

**I have written:**

routes.rb:

```
# added param: :title
resources :posts, param: :title do
  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]

resources  :images do
  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
end

resources  :links do
  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create]
end
resources :photos, only: [:new, :create,:destroy]
resources :songs, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

**bundle exec rake routes:**

```
/posts/new(.:format)            posts#new
/posts/:title/edit(.:format)    posts#edit
/posts/:title(.:format)         posts#show
/posts/:title(.:format)         posts#update
/posts/:title(.:format)         posts#update
/posts/:title(.:format)         posts#destroy
```

**post_controller.rb:**

```
def set_post
   @post = Post.find(params[:title])
end
```

**Blog works, but url is post/5 (for example). How to make url like: post/my_post_title?**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :show]
  respond_to :html, :json, :rss, :atom
  def index
    if params[:search].blank?
      @posts = Post.includes(:comments, :photos).all
    else
      @search = Post.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
      end
      @posts = @search.results
    end
    respond_with(@posts)
  end

  def show
    set_post
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def edit
    set_post
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    # responder gem doc
    @post.errors.add(:base, :invalid) unless @post.save#test
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def update
    set_post
    if @post.valid?
      @post.update(post_params)
    else
      # responder gem doc
      @post.errors.add(:base, :invalid)
    end
     respond_with(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    set_post
    @post.destroy
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def feed
    @posts = Post.all.reverse
    respond_with(@posts)
  end

  def archive
    @posts_by_year = Post.limit(300).all.order("created_at DESC").
    group_by {|post| post.created_at.beginning_of_year}
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:title])
  end


  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

All routes:

```
# == Route Map
#
#                           Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                                Controller#Action
#                             feed GET      /feed(.:format)                                            posts#feed
#                          archive GET      /archive(.:format)                                         posts#archive
#                 new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                                   devise/sessions#new
#                     user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                                   devise/sessions#create
#             destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                  devise/sessions#destroy
# user_facebook_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/facebook(.:format)                             callbacks#passthru
#  user_facebook_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/facebook/callback(.:format)                    callbacks#facebook
#                    user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)                                  devise/passwords#create
#                new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                              devise/passwords#new
#               edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                             devise/passwords#edit
#                                  PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                                  devise/passwords#update
#                                  PUT      /users/password(.:format)                                  devise/passwords#update
#         cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                                    devise/registrations#cancel
#                user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                                           devise/registrations#create
#            new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#new
#           edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                                      devise/registrations#edit
#                                  PATCH    /users(.:format)                                           devise/registrations#update
#                                  PUT      /users(.:format)                                           devise/registrations#update
#                                  DELETE   /users(.:format)                                           devise/registrations#destroy
#                             root GET      /                                                          posts#index
#                    post_comments POST     /posts/:post_title/comments(.:format)                      comments#create
#                 new_post_comment GET      /posts/:post_title/comments/new(.:format)                  comments#new
#              post_image_comments POST     /posts/:post_title/images/:image_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create
#           new_post_image_comment GET      /posts/:post_title/images/:image_id/comments/new(.:format) comments#new
#                      post_images GET      /posts/:post_title/images(.:format)                        images#index
#                                  POST     /posts/:post_title/images(.:format)                        images#create
#                   new_post_image GET      /posts/:post_title/images/new(.:format)                    images#new
#                  edit_post_image GET      /posts/:post_title/images/:id/edit(.:format)               images#edit
#                       post_image GET      /posts/:post_title/images/:id(.:format)                    images#show
#                                  PATCH    /posts/:post_title/images/:id(.:format)                    images#update
#                                  PUT      /posts/:post_title/images/:id(.:format)                    images#update
#                                  DELETE   /posts/:post_title/images/:id(.:format)                    images#destroy
#               post_link_comments POST     /posts/:post_title/links/:link_id/comments(.:format)       comments#create
#            new_post_link_comment GET      /posts/:post_title/links/:link_id/comments/new(.:format)   comments#new
#                       post_links GET      /posts/:post_title/links(.:format)                         links#index
#                                  POST     /posts/:post_title/links(.:format)                         links#create
#                    new_post_link GET      /posts/:post_title/links/new(.:format)                     links#new
#                   edit_post_link GET      /posts/:post_title/links/:id/edit(.:format)                links#edit
#                        post_link GET      /posts/:post_title/links/:id(.:format)                     links#show
#                                  PATCH    /posts/:post_title/links/:id(.:format)                     links#update
#                                  PUT      /posts/:post_title/links/:id(.:format)                     links#update
#                                  DELETE   /posts/:post_title/links/:id(.:format)                     links#destroy
#                      post_photos POST     /posts/:post_title/photos(.:format)                        photos#create
#                   new_post_photo GET      /posts/:post_title/photos/new(.:format)                    photos#new
#                       post_photo DELETE   /posts/:post_title/photos/:id(.:format)                    photos#destroy
#                       post_songs POST     /posts/:post_title/songs(.:format)                         songs#create
#                    new_post_song GET      /posts/:post_title/songs/new(.:format)                     songs#new
#                        post_song DELETE   /posts/:post_title/songs/:id(.:format)                     songs#destroy
#                            posts GET      /posts(.:format)                                           posts#index
#                                  POST     /posts(.:format)                                           posts#create
#                         new_post GET      /posts/new(.:format)                                       posts#new
#                        edit_post GET      /posts/:title/edit(.:format)                               posts#edit
#                             post GET      /posts/:title(.:format)                                    posts#show
#                                  PATCH    /posts/:title(.:format)                                    posts#update
#                                  PUT      /posts/:title(.:format)                                    posts#update
#                                  DELETE   /posts/:title(.:format)                                    posts#destroy
#
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ........

**post_controller.rb:**

Find will only work with params[:id]

```
def set_post
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

To find with title you need to use :

```
def set_post
  @post = Post.find_by(title: params[:title])
end
```

**Here, to make url like: post/my_post_title? there is a good Gem, You can also try this...**

You need to use `FriendlyId gem`

```
# Gemfile
gem 'friendly_id'

rails generate friendly_id    
rake db:migrate

# edit app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title_post, use: :slugged
end

# If you're adding FriendlyId to an existing app and need
# to generate slugs for existing users, do this from the
# console, runner, or add a Rake task:
Post.find_each(&:save)
```

For more details please refer this link [freindly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Hope this will work for you.